# Find the value of this integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I have only recently been learning integration, so pardon me if this is trivial. Frankly, I am not sure how to even read this question; my attempts are very disordered and confused. Elementary guidance would be much appreciated. Is it connected to the fundamental theorem of calculus in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that after the substitution $x=2t$ we have that
$$\int_2^4f(x)dx=2\int_1^2f(2t)dt=16\int_1^2f(t)dt=16\int_0^2f(t)dt-16\sqrt{2}.$$
In a similar way, 
$$
\int_0^2f(t)dt=2\int_{0}^{1}f(2t)dt=16\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt=16\sqrt{2}.$$
which implies that
$$\int_2^4f(x)dx=(16^2-16)\sqrt{2}=240\sqrt{2}.$$

P.S. Another approach (though very similar to the previous one).
$$\int_2^4f(x)dx=\int_0^4f(x)dx-\int_0^2f(x)dx=4\int_0^1f(4t)dt-2\int_0^1f(2t)dt\\=4\cdot 8^2\int_0^1f(t)dt-2\cdot 8\int_0^1f(t)dt
=240\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Not too sure, but I can get so far as to use the substitution into f(2x) to get f(4t). However, I'm afraid my inexperience prevents me from seeing how to use the given integral to evaluate even the much clearer (thank you!!) modified form you provided.

Comment: @cgug123 Now use $f(2t)=8f(t)$.

Comment: I can do that and get up to a very simple looking integral; what confuses me is how to use one integral on one interval to evaluate another on a different interval. Can't seem to connect the two.

Comment: @cgug123  See my edited answer.

Comment: @Dominik You are right. Let me edit...

Comment: @robertz You don't need the complicated decomposition of the integration interval. A simple substitution directly yields the integral over $[0, 2]$ from the integral over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Dominik Thanks... never answer on MSE instead of going to sleep...

Comment: That was a really beautiful solution. If you don't mind me asking, can you please explain how you knew what the substitution to make was?

Comment: @cgug123 In this case the main hint was the relation $f(2x)=8f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Change of variables $x = 2t$ on
$ \int_2^4 f(x)\; dx$